# JSON data changes based on request client

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, cakephp, datatables

I have a CakePHP controller that returns a JSON object.  If I request the content directly with a browser (Chrome, in this instance) I get back what I expect.

Fiddler shows me what I expect to see. (Image here because I don't have enough reputation points)

https://s14.postimg.org/ajkh5e3ox/filddle_right.png

However, if I had that same request to jQuery's ajax API, the response comes back modified.

Fiddler shows me what I don't expect to see.

https://s12.postimg.org/5g8ip5q25/fiddle_wrong.png

You can see that something has modified the data structure (adding the content field) and encoding the quotations into their unicode equivalents.  I'm trying to feed this into a jQuery.DataTables() object, if that matters.

Anyway, I'm stumped.  Any clues for the clueless?

Edit:

The request headers for the non-expected behavior look like this

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:10.11.3.4
Referer:http://10.11.3.4/test.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Whereas the one that behaves like I think it should is thus:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:10.11.3.4
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
```

So it looks like the Accept: header in the request that "works."  If I set it to 'text' the request changes appropriately, and the data returned looks good, but it is still being escaped.

Not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

what does your jquery request look like?

a common mistake is not setting the 'json' flags or other appropriate header flags on the jquery request.

might be a good idea to look at the request headers for each request and see what's different.  one way your server's sending back stringified json content to the browser as a payload, the second way is sending back *an escaped string of json content* as the 'content' paramenter of a stringified json object.

in fact, in this case you may actually need to *remove* the json flags on your jquery request to get it to respond more like the browser request.

good luck!

Comment: The request itself is made through DataTable's API, but my understanding is that it is passed directly to the jQuery AJAX API.

Comment: So I've figured out this isn't a problem with the JSON/AJAX request, it's a problem with CakePHP's JSON builder templates.  I'm getting fully formed JSON from the DB, and the template thinks it needs to turn that into JSON, too.  Hence the encoding, and hence the "content" key addition.

I have't figured out how to turn this off yet, but I'll go bug the Cake guys to figure it out.

Comment: glad you're getting somewhere!  maybe skip the cakephp encoding, or decode the db's json either in php before sending it to the template -- worst case you might be able to deparse the result in the jquery result function.  good luck!

Comment: Right now what I'm doing is setting the content-type header on the response to text/plain, which prevents Cake from trying to encode it for me, but causes me to have to manually parse it into a JSON object on the client side.

Discussion on that is here...

http://discourse.cakephp.org/t/pass-through-json-data-with-json-view/1068